# How to truncate string to first n words in PHP

Tags: php, html, truncate

I would like to truncate a very long string, formatted via html elements.

I need the first 500 words (somehow I have to avoid html tags `<p>`, `<br>` while my function truncating the string), but in the result I have to keep/use those html elements because the result also should be formatted by html tags like the "original whole" text.

What's the best way to truncate my string?

Example:

Original text

```
> <p><a href="/t/the-huffington-post">The Huffington Post</a> (via <a
> href="/t/daily-mail">Daily Mail</a>) is reporting that <a
> href="/t/misty">Misty</a> has been returned to a high kill shelter for
> farting too much! She appeared on Greenville County Pet Rescue’s
> “urgent” list, which means if she doesn’t get readopted, she will be
> euthanized!</p>
```

I need the first n words (n=10)

```
>  <p><a href="/t/the-huffington-post">The Huffington Post</a> (via <a
> href="/t/daily-mail">Daily Mail</a>) is reporting that.. </p>
```

Comment: Can you clarify by giving an example string, and an example end result. A before and after example

Comment: What are you using to do your truncating, javascript, PHP or what language?

Comment: @jtorrescr The title and the tags say PHP

Comment: Maybe try this function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php#73577

Comment: Hi Nagy. How did you get on with the answers below? It is quite usual here to vote on, reply to, or accept (tick) answers, so the folks below know if their work was helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

A brute force method would be to just split all elements on blanks, then iterate over them. You count only non-tag elements up to a maximum, while you output tags nonetheless. Something along these lines:

```
$string = "your string here";
$output = "";
$count = 0;
$max = 10;
$tokens = preg_split('/ /', $string);
foreach ($tokens as $token)
{
  if (preg_match('/<.*?>/', $token)) {
    $output .= "$token ";
  } else if ($count < $max) {
    $output .= "$token ";
    $count += 1;
  }
}
print $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have [found something like this](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/truncate/) with some Googling.

```
  // Original PHP code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
  // Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.

  function restoreTags($input)
  {
    $opened = array();

    // loop through opened and closed tags in order
    if(preg_match_all("/<(\/?[a-z]+)>?/i", $input, $matches)) {
      foreach($matches[1] as $tag) {
        if(preg_match("/^[a-z]+$/i", $tag, $regs)) {
          // a tag has been opened
          if(strtolower($regs[0]) != 'br') $opened[] = $regs[0];
        } elseif(preg_match("/^\/([a-z]+)$/i", $tag, $regs)) {
          // a tag has been closed
          unset($opened[array_pop(array_keys($opened, $regs[1]))]);
        }
      }
    }

    // close tags that are still open
    if($opened) {
      $tagstoclose = array_reverse($opened);
      foreach($tagstoclose as $tag) $input .= "</$tag>";
    }

    return $input;
  }
```

When you combine it with another function mentioned in the article:

```
  function truncateWords($input, $numwords, $padding="")
  {
    $output = strtok($input, " \n");
    while(--$numwords > 0) $output .= " " . strtok(" \n");
    if($output != $input) $output .= $padding;
    return $output;
  }
```

Then you can just achieve what you're looking for by doing this:

```
$originalText = '...'; // some original text in HTML format
$output = truncateWords($originalText, 500); // This truncates to 500 words (ish...)
$output = restoreTags($output); // This fixes any open tags
```